# Matplotlib live plot relim after using navigation bar in tkinter gui

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter

I am making a gui in tkinter with live, embedded matplotlib graphs. I am using `FigureCanvasTkAgg` for the canvas, `NavigationToolbar2Tk` for the navigation bar, and `FuncAnimation` to handle periodic updates of the given source of data.

The callback tied to `FuncAnimation` resets the data on a given line (i.e. the return value from `Axes.plot(...)`) every invocation (i.e. `Line2D.set_data(...)`). The callback also redetermines and applies the appropriate x- and y-axis limits to fit the new data via

```
axis.relim()
axis.autoscale_view()
```

where `axis` is an instance of `AxesSubplot`.

*Before* the navigation bar is used, this works great; any new data added is appropriately reflected in the graph and the axes automatically re-scale to fit it, which was my goal.

The problem I am facing is that if any of the functions on the navigation bar are used (pan, zoom, etc.) the re-scaling fails to work any longer, meaning the graph may grow out of view and the user's only way to see new data is to manually pan over to it or to manually zoom out, which is undesirable.

Realistically, this functionality make sense since it would be annoying to, for example, try to zoom in a part of the plot only to have it zoom out immediately to refit the axes to new data, which is why I had intended to add a `tkinter.Checkbutton` to temporarily disable the re-scaling.

I've tried to look into the source for the navigation bar, and it seems to change state on the axes and canvas which I can only assume is the problem, but I have so far been unsuccessful at finding a way to "undo" these changes. If such a way exists, I would bind it to a `tkinter.Button` or something so the automatic re-scaling can be re-enabled.

How might I fix this problem?

Below is a minimal example that demonstrates this problem.

```
import math
import itertools
import tkinter as tk
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg, NavigationToolbar2Tk
from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation


def xydata_generator(func, div):
    for num in itertools.count():
        num = num / div
        yield num, func(num)


class Plot(tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, master, data_source, interval=100, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(master, *args, **kwargs)

        self.data_source = data_source
        self.figure = Figure((5, 5), 100)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(self.figure, self)
        self.nav_bar = NavigationToolbar2Tk(self.canvas, self)
        self.canvas.get_tk_widget().pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
        self.axis = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
        self.x_data = []
        self.y_data = []
        self.line = self.axis.plot([], [])[0]  # Axes.plot returns a list
        # Set the data to a mutable type so we only need to append to it then force the line to invalidate its cache
        self.line.set_data(self.x_data, self.y_data)
        self.ani = FuncAnimation(self.figure, self.update_plot, interval=interval)

    def update_plot(self, _):
        x, y = next(self.data_source)  # (realistically the data source wouldn't be restricted to be a generator)
        # Because the Line2D object stores a reference to the two lists, we need only update the lists and signal
        # that the line needs to be updated.
        self.x_data.append(x)
        self.y_data.append(y)
        self.line.recache_always()
        self._refit_artists()

    def _refit_artists(self):
        self.axis.relim()
        self.axis.autoscale_view()


root = tk.Tk()
data = xydata_generator(math.sin, 5)
plot = Plot(root, data)
plot.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out to be pretty simple. To reset the axes so that the calls to `Axes.relim()` and `Axes.autoscale_view()` take effect, one simply needs to call `Axes.set_autoscale_on(True)`. This must be repeated every time the functions on the navigation bar (pan, zoom, etc.) are used.

Comment: And how would one do that? Could you explain where and how exactly one needs to call ```Axes.set_autoscale_on(True)``` ?  I'm trying to do something similar myself.

Comment: @Nachiket This was a long time ago, so I can't remember exactly, but I think I manually added a tkinter button whose callback simply executed `Axes.set_autoscale_on(True)`. This way the user could use the navigation buttons to zoom in somewhere, for example, then they could press the manually-added button whenever they wanted to re-enable auto-scaling.